# Reading and displaying data from multiple .txt files

Tags: java

How do you read data from multiple .txt files? I want to be able to print the contents of two .txt files in a program, but I only know how to do one.

Comment: if you know how to do it with one... what stops you from doing the same again with another one?

Comment: Do one first. Then do another. The same way.

Comment: Please provide comments on your platform, language, etc, and how you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: In the future, show your attempts to solve your problem with your question. This question to be honest was pretty bad and suggest that you're lazy (even if you're not) since you showed no attempt. Hopefully your future questions will be better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create two streams and read the files from them separately.

```
ObjectInputStream in1 = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file1.dat");
ObjectInputStream in2 = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file2.dat");

Object obj1 = in1.readObject();
Object obj2 = in2.readObject();
```

I think this should work (changing Object to the type of your object and casting the return of the readObject function).

But since you want to input two text files, you had better using the Scanner class:

```
    Scanner in1 = new Scanner(new File("file1.txt"));
    Scanner in2 = new Scanner(new File("file2.txt"));
    String s = null;
    while (s += in1.nextLine() != null);
    while (s += in2.nextLine() != null);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Actually you should add a try catch block but basically that's the thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use two variables (I haven't tested the code but this is the basic idea):

```
// Open both files
FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream("file1.txt");
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis1));

FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("file2.txt");
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis2));

String strLine1;
String strLine2;

// Read and print a line from each file
while ((strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null || (strLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println (strLine1);
  System.out.println (strLine2);
}

// Close the FileInputStreams
br1.close();
br2.close();
```